# Linking promise chains

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a working promise chain:

```
function startSync(db) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    syncCats(db)
      .then(syncTrees(db))
      .then(syncCars(db))
      ...  
      .then(resolve());
  });
return promise;
}
```

This works great. It performs each of those function calls, waiting for each one to complete before firing off another. Each of those functions returns a promise, like so:

```
function syncCaesar(db) {
  var promise = new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    // do aysnc db calls, and whatnot, resolving/rejecting appropriately
  }
return promise;
}
```

I need to run this chain on a series of databases, sequentially.
I've tried other solutions here, but they would fire off `syncCats()` all at once.

For instance:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve();
dbs.forEach(function(db) {
  promise = promise.then(startSync(db));
}
```

Fires off `syncCats(db[0])` and `syncCats(db[1])` simultaneously.

Edit:

Performing `startSync(dbs[0]).then(startSync(dbs[1]));` acts the same.

Edit2: Also performs the same:

```
dbs.forEach(function(db) {
  promise = promise.then(function() {
    return startSync(db);
  }
}
```

Comment: Promises 101 ... `.then` expects it's arguments to be **function**, ignores any argument that is not a function - you are supplying the result of calling a function - try `promise.then(() => startSync(db));` or `promise.then(function() {return startSync(db);});` if ES2016+ scares you ... even in your "edit" - you are still doing the same mistake for `dbs[1]`

Comment: note: your whole forEach code can be rewritten - `dbs.reduce((promise, db) => promise.then(() => startSync(db)), Promise.resolve());`

Comment: Hmm. See edit2, I had tried that previously.

Comment: Hmm ... did you fix **ALL** your `.then`'s in `startSync` that are also written incorrectly?

Comment: Wait, they're incorrect in `startSync`? As T.J points out, I'm _italic_ calling the function, then returning it to sync. But, it works. It executes sequentially, every time...

Comment: `Wait, they're incorrect in startSync` - sure are - each call to `startSync` will resolve "immediately" not waiting for any of the async functions within to finish

Comment: @JaromandaX Any idea why they _would_ be running sequentially?

Comment: I have no reason to believe that they are - having no access to syncTrees or syncCars etc I can only assume that those functions return a function

Comment: They're all the same as `syncCaesar()`. I have continued to test, and they have run sequentially for a few days now.

Comment: it's not that I don't believe you, it's just that's not how .then works ... are these native promises? or some obscure non APlus conformant Promise library?

Comment: the other highly suspicious thing is ... you call `startSync` passing in `db` as an argument .... but your `startSync` function doesn't accept an argument!

Comment: Yep, native. And typo fixed. I'm guessing that opening a mysql connection is holding it up somehow, but I don't see how that'd be possible if it can spawn multiple sequential chains in parallel

Comment: Here's why all the operations *may* look like they are in sequence ... because they all **start** synchronously, in the right sequence

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree, but I've absolutely abused `console.log`, and each says 'start' and 'end'. They never overlap. I've even shuffled the order they execute in around, and it's always perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *calling* `startSync` and then passing its return value in to `then`. So naturally, if you do that twice, it's going to start the process twice in parallel.

Instead, pass in a function that doesn't call `startSync` until it's called:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve();
dbs.forEach(function(db) {
  promise = promise.then(function() { startSync(db); });
});
```

or with ES2015:

```
let promise = Promise.resolve();
dbs.forEach(function(db) {
  promise = promise.then(_ => startSync(db));
});
```

---

Separately, three things jump out about `startSync`:

1. It starts all its operations in parallel, not sequentially
2. It exhibits the *promise creation anti-pattern*. There's no reason for `startSync` to create a new promise; it *already has* a promise it can work with
3. It ensures that its resolution value is `undefined`

If you really want the operations running in parallel like that, I suggest being more explicit about it:

```
function startSync(db) {
  return Promise.all([
    syncCats(db),
    syncTrees(db),
    syncCars(db)
  ])
  .then(_ => undefined); // This does #3
}
```

...but you could also do to avoid the anti-pattern:

```
// Still run in parallel!
function startSync(db) {
  return syncCats(db)
    .then(syncTrees(db))
    .then(syncCars(db))
    .then(_ => undefined); // Does #3
}
```

If you meant for them to be sequential, you need to pass functions, not the result of calling them:

```
function startSync(db) {
  return syncCats(db)
    .then(_ => syncTrees(db))
    .then(_ => syncCars(db))
    .then(_ => undefined);  // Again, does #3
}
```

If you made `syncCats`, `syncTrees`, and `syncCars` resolve their promises with `db`, like this:

```
function syncCats(db) {
    return startSomethingAsync().then(_ => db);
}
```

...then it could be:

```
function startSync(db) {
  return syncCats(db)
    .then(syncTrees)
    .then(syncCars)
    .then(_ => undefined);  // Only here for #3
}
```

...since each would receive `db` as its first argument.

Finally, if you don't need to force `undefined` as the promise resolution value, I suggest dropping that part from the above. :-)

Comment: Each one is making a call to a mysql db, working with the data, and storing it in mongo. All together, a lengthy affair for each. I see immediately the mistake I'm making, but... **why is it working?** They're running sequentially.

Comment: @mtro: Probably whatever you're calling is putting them in a sequence. They'll **start** in the order you had them, but they don't wait to start the next one, they just go ahead and start that too immediately after. So I suspect subsequent calls on a connection busy doing something else are being queued by that layer. But they're not put in sequence by the code in the question, if that makes sense.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it does make sense. Something has to be making them sequential, if it's not the way I have it laid out. But that doesn't explain why if I toss the `startSync()` into a `forEach` that it fires of a number of _still sequential_ chains...

Comment: @mtro: If they're different databases, I could easily see the DB layer serializing the calls for a given DB (e.g., the connection only allowing a single query at a time, that would be normal) but allowing calls to separate DBs in parallel (because it's a different connection).

Answer (score 0):

With appreciation to T.J and Jaromanda, I was able to solve it by fixing how `startSync()` was resolved:

```
function startSync(db) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

   syncCats(db)
      .then(syncTrees(db)) // not correct way to call, see below
      .then(syncCars(db))
      ...  
      .then(function() { resolve(); });
  });
 return promise;
}
```

Now, as T.J points out, the way each of the `.then`'s is being called is incorrect. He explains it better in his answer. I'm being saved by some misunderstood database layer queueing. `syncTrees()` and `syncCars()` *should* be running in parallel.

Comment: If you want the individual parts of `startSync` running in parallel, as I said in my answer, `Promise.all` would be the usual way to do that. The above still reads as though it were by accident... (And still creates a promise unnecessarily.) :-)

Comment: I want every part of `startSync` sequential, and every iteration of `startSync` sequential. So the promise is necessary, yes?

Comment: No. Any time you *already* have a promise, there's no need to use `new Promise`; `then` and `catch` create new promises. Also, the above does not (intentionally) make the individual parts of `startSync` sequential (the work they're doing may end up being put in series by something else, but you don't want to rely on that). If you want them sequential, do what I showed in my answer for *"If you meant for them to be sequential"*

Comment: Finally, the above will result in unhandled promise rejections if (say) `syncTrees` and `syncCars` both fail. If I'm guessing right that you're using Node, as of recent Node versions, that'll terminate your process.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood it correctly, you will be having an array of databases and you want to sync them one by one i.e. sync for dbs[0], once that is complete sync for dbs[1], and so on. If that's correct you can do something like this.

```
var syncMultipleDBs = (dataBases) {
    var db = dataBases.shift();
    if (!db) {
        return;
    }
    startSync(db).then(syncMultipleDBs.bind(null, dataBases));
};

syncsyncMultipleDBs(dbs.slice());
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: @mtro - am I right that this would be an infinite loop that would lock up the main "thread" - unless something throws an error because `db` would be undefined at some point? but it would be ungraceful

Comment: @GunjanGupta - instead of me answering that question, how about you tell me what you think would stop the recursion? ahh, you removed the comment - saw your error

Comment: Ya, Saw that I missed the if condition. But I was never trying to give a 100% answer, just the idea how it can be made sequential